# sql create temporary table invalid identifier exception

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE m_product_forecast (
    m_product_forecast_id   NUMBER
        NOT NULL ENABLE,
    forecast_mode           CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'D'
        NOT NULL ENABLE,
    forecast_qty            NUMBER DEFAULT 1
        NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CHECK ( forecast_mode IN (
        'D',
        'P'
    ) ) ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_KEY" PRIMARY KEY ( "m_product_forecast_id",
                                                      "forecast_mode" )
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

The exception is

> ORA-00904: "m_product_forecast_id" : identificateur non valide

What is wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the double quotes: `"`

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) `"m_product_forecast_id"` is a different name than `m_product_forecast_id`